# What does ‘contract ‘ mean here?

Tags: meaning

“The boy sulkily complied, muttering at first, but desisting when he looked round and saw that Quilp was following him with a steady look. And here it may be remarked, that between this boy and the dwarf that existed a strange kind of mutual liking. How born or bred, and or nourished upon blows and threats on one side, and retorts and defiances on the other, is not to the purpose. Quilp would certainly suffer nobody to **contract** him but the boy, and the boy would assuredly not have submitted to be so knocked about by anybody but Quilp, when he had the power to run away at any time he chose.”

Excerpt From
The Old Curiosity Shop
Charles Dickens

Comment: When asking about the meaning of a word, you should explain what you found on your own and why it didn't resolve the issue. I close-voted because I didn't see any evidence of that. That being said, this appears to be a simple typo for "contradict". (Also, "that existed" appears to be a typo for "there existed". You might have a bad copy of this story.)

Comment: I think talk to him boldly

Comment: It's being used as a verb, and it's in the dictionary. "to make a legal agreement with someone to do work or to have work done for you"

Comment: My copy of the book has **contradict**, but Google Ngrams shows quite a few editions with 'contract', so it seems to be a misprint that has got in and been unthinkingly copied.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a transcription / OCR error

Answer (score -2):

> What does ‘contract ‘ mean here?

Here "to contract" basically means "to hire". "to contract" (verb) is the act of entering a legal relationship, a "contract" (noun). The way the word is used here it is clear that the contract would encompass working, perhaps with a specified task as the goal of the work. Like this:

> I contract you to mow the grass in my garden.

Comment: Not relevant here. The boy wasn't hiring Quilp to do work for him.

Comment: @KateBunting: you are commenting on your knowledge of a certain book, i was commenting on the question as it was asked. It doesn't - for the question as posed - matter if "contract" is a misprint or not. This is a *language* forum, not a *literature* one.

Comment: Almost *any* sequence of words can be twisted into some kind of contrived meaning. I actually guessed initially that the mistranscribed word might have been ***contact***. Which is actually easier to justify than ***contract***, here. But what's the point? The only "right" word is the one Dickens wrote.